# Does rselenium in the older version of R still work?

Tags: r

I have used RSelenium to scrape web content in the past, but recently I updated R on my computer and can no longer use RSelenium. Furthermore, even if I install the old version of R and continue to use RSelenium, somehow RSelenium ceases to work with Firefox, my chosen browser. Is anyone out there using RSelenium nowadays to scrape webcontent? Is it working for you? If yes, please share some tips.

My specific problem is that once I ran 
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()

My firefox browser just keeps opening up new windows and will not stop. If I manually stops it, the connection will be lost.

If anyone knows solution to this problem, please share. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/splashr/

Comment: Please elaborate more on what you mean by not working (expected vs actual result). Give any error messages you may have received.

Comment: @Aaron, I just modified the post based on your comment. Please let me know if you have a solution to this problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Aurèle, thank you for the link. Looks very useful for my purpose!